# Database slice the last two characters of the password (?!)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a very frustrating problem. I have a client which send a registration form to the server. The handler is a php file.

The problem is the following: the client send the form data to the php, the php store it in the mysql database. But if I try to give a name which is contains a space - I don't know why - in the database the the password's length is reduced by two.

I searched long hours, but found nothing. I'm on the edge of madness, so I would like to ask you to help me to find the problem.

Here is the registration form:

```
<!-- REGISTRATION -->
    <div data-role="page" id="regScreen">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="profileCircle">
                <img src="img/iskola.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="space"></div>
            <form action="" method="post" id="regForm" name="regForm">
                <input type="text" name="nev" id="regName" placeholder="Teljes név" data-mini="true"/>
                <input type="email" name="mail" id="regEmail" placeholder="Email cím" data-mini="true"/>
                <input type="password" name="jelszo" id="regPassword" placeholder="Jelszó" data-mini="true"/>
                <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="Regisztráció" name="rendben" id="rendben" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="#loginScreen"><div class="circle leftBottom c1">
            <img src="img/ikonok/vissza.png" />
        </div></a>
    </div>
```

This is the script which should handle the registration on the client side:

```
function registration(){
var name = $('#regForm #regName').val();
var email = $('#regForm #regEmail').val();
var password = $('#regForm #regPassword').val();
if((password == "" || password == null) || (email == "" || email == null)){
    navigator.notification.alert("Nem töltött ki minden adatot!", function(){}, "Figyelem!");
}else{
    $.ajax({
        url: host + "regisztracio.php",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {rendben:'ok', nev: name, mail: email, jelszo: password},                      
        success: function(data){
            if(data.ok){
                    navigator.notification.alert('Sikeresen regisztrált!\nMostmár be tud jelentkezni a saját felhasználónevével!',function(){
                    $.mobile.changePage("#loginScreen");
                },'Üdvözöljük!');
            }else{
                navigator.notification.alert(data.uzenet,function(){},'Figyelem!');
                if(data.help){
                    navigator.notification.confirm('Kívánja, hogy új jelszót küldjünk erre az email címre?',function(){
                        console.log(button);
                    }, 'Segíthetünk?', 'Igen, Nem');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log('jajj');
            navigator.notification.alert(err.message,function(){},'Hiba!');
        }
    });
}
}
```

And finally here is the php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['rendben'])) {

require("mysql.php");

$nev   = $_POST['nev'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$jelszo = $_POST['jelszo'];

if (empty($_POST['nev']) OR empty($_POST['mail']) OR empty($_POST['jelszo'])) { 
    $string = array("ok" => false, "uzenet" => "Nem töltött ki minden adatot!");
    echo json_encode($string);
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM felhasznalok
        WHERE mail = '{$mail}'";
    $eredmeny = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($eredmeny) == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO felhasznalok
                (nev, mail, jelszo, kep)
                VALUES
                ('{$nev}', '{$mail}', '{$jelszo}', '{$kep}')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        $string = array("ok" => true);
        echo json_encode($string);
    }else{
        $string = array("ok" => false, "help" => true, "uzenet" => "Ezzel az email címmel már regisztráltak, lehet, hogy elfelejtette a jelszavát?");
        echo json_encode($string);
    }
}
}?>
```

If you need I will upload a picture from the database table.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: How long is the password field in the database table?

Comment: Plain text passwords in your database, ..really? Also, I hope the lack of server-side sanitisation here is because you simplified your example for us :) it looks wide open to sql-injection.

Comment: What kind of notation are those '{$somevar}' expression in php?

Comment: I thought this is the problem, so from 50 I increased to 100 and the password what I type in is only 6 characters

Comment: I suggest you dump the final sql statements before you execute them. This way you can narrow down the cause.

Comment: You should really `mysql_real_escape_string()` your user inputs before using them in queries. Right now both of your queries are wide-open to SQL injection.

Comment: Paul S, Before I uploaded the question I encrypted the password on the client side, and my friend did some 'magic' with the php. But in the end I gave up, and deleted these part of the scripts.

arkascha, I don't know but it is works.

Comment: @Gábor "it is works"? Obviously not. Please echo out the whole query before you send it to the server with `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Sorry, you don't know what those expressions do, what they are there for, but you use them? Em...

Comment: I replaced the '{$variable}' to '".$variable."' but it still don't work :(

Comment: Using `{}` around a variable in a string is perfectly OK in PHP, in fact it allows you to use array indexes and object properties in a string without having to resort to the dot concatenation approach. Also, some editors (Aptana and Zend (that I know of)) will also highlight that variable in the string when surrounded with curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are having troubles with `jQuery.param` encoding of spaces (+, one character, instead of %20, three characters).

You can try manually replacing the ' ' with '%20' in the password field (note: you probably have the same problem in *all* fields, only you haven't noticed it yet) using the `.beforeSend` [setting](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
url: host + "regisztracio.php",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {rendben:'ok', nev: name, mail: email, jelszo: password},     
    beforeSend: function (req, data) {
        data.jelszo = data.jelszo.replace(/\+/g, "%20");
    },
    success: function(data){
        ...
```

Also (but this is **unrelated**), on the PHP side, notice that you can simplify a bit your code to encode the answer in one place only:

```
$string = array("ok" => false);

// Ez ad némi biztonságot
$fields = array('nev','mail','jelszo');
foreach($fields as $field)
{
    if (empty($_POST[$field]))
        $string['uzenet'] = "Nem töltött ki minden adatot: ${field}!";
    else
        ${$field} = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]);
}
if (!isset($string['uzenet']) {
    $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM felhasznalok
        WHERE mail = '{$mail}'";
    $eredmeny = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($eredmeny) == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO felhasznalok
                (nev, mail, jelszo, kep)
                VALUES
                ('{$nev}', '{$mail}', '{$jelszo}', '{$kep}')";
        if (false === mysql_query($sql))
            $string['uzenet'] = 'Volt egy adatbázis hiba!';
        else
            $string['ok'] = true;
    }else{
        $string['help'] = true;
        $string['uzenet'] = 'Ezzel az email címmel már regisztráltak, lehet, hogy elfelejtette a jelszavát?';
    }
}
die(json_encode($string)); // No more output after this.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive not a full answer as such but the formatting is better than a comment:

As others have already suggested:

1. Echo your sql statement.  This is what is being stored in the db after all. This will show you whether your problem lies before or after the data is stored in the db.
2. var_dump($_POST) if your sql is good as this checks the code in between the receipt of data and its storage in the DB - you can see what your script actually sends.
3. escape your text to prevent 'sql injection' - Always escape the text because you never know when you are going to change your client page and it is safer that way.  Your case is a prime example of why you never trust data from the client.

FWIIW, I suspect that the problem lies in the javascript.  One problem with the use of libraries like jquery is that they actually don't make easy stuff easier.  They make it more complex.  A bit like a slide rule though, once learned, they make some complicated stuff no harder than the easy stuff.  There is a code-portability benefit too.

Even so, IMHO, for a simple ajax call, you're actually better off using pure JS, certainly as a beginner.  w3schools.com has an excellent AJAX tutorial and code examples.

mysql_* extensions are deprecated.  You would be wise to learn mysqli_ (which is nearly identical) or PDO.